# The chicken or the egg dilemma in Java

Tags: java, design-patterns

Object is on the top of Java classes.
String is a subclass of Object.

So, what was first - Object or String?

The prompt answer is - Object.

But the interesting thing is that Object already has a method toString(), and thus "knows" about String. So, when Object is constructed, the String has to already exist. On the other hand, String is a subclass of Object, and when String is constructed Object has to already exist. We fall into a never ending definition cycle (and some technical problem, too). Such approach at least violates the idea of a single root class.

The concern may look like rather theoretical, than practical.

But the thing is that I see a similar approach in other frameworks.
I think at least to some extent it was inspired by the way core Java classes were design.

What do you think - are circular dependencies between Java classes in general (and particular in case of Object/String) inevitable? 
Shouldn't they be avoided at any cost? 
Or can they be accepted sometimes (with discretion and caution) as the result of a reasonable compromise? If, so - what are the criteria?

Comment: I know ! This is a joke... :)

Comment: @Orabîg no problem. Jokes are welcomed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java hasn't a one-pass compiler but a multi-pass compiler.

This means that all classes that are compiled together are really at the declaration level. Even if they have circular dependencies these are solved in a first step so the fact that `Object` class provides a `toString` method does not conceptually mean anything in relation to having or less a root class.

Since we're talking about theoretical issues the relation between a class declaration and and which is the real root class is resolved easily:

**`Object` is the root class just because `String` inherits from it.**

The `String toString()` is nothing more that a signature that is useful to the compiler to grant type safety, `Object` doesn't require a `String` object, it doesn't even need to know what a `String` is.

Comment: Well, if doesn't need to know what String is, how is it planning to return an object of String type from toString() method? At least Object is supposed to be able to construct a String instance and return it. How can it be done without some knowledge of String?

Comment: I am just trying to clarify. Anyway, sir, you answer looks like the best one, so I'll wait for some time and most likely accept it (plus vote up for other good answers).

Answer (score 2):

I think circular dependencies between *classes* are not necessarily a problem and happen fairly frequently (for solid design reasons). Say you have a tree and a node that know about each other, or a linked list and a node, etc. In such cases the circular dependency is perfectly reasonable.

What I am less fond of is circular dependencies between *modules*. These generally can, and in my view should, be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

Since both Object and String were in the first version of Java, I think they both came at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

The "problem" as you are describing it sounds as if you believe Java is a scripting language in which one has to be declared first for the other to be in it's scope, but this is not the case as Java is a compiled language which means such dependencies are resolved at compile-time.

Comment: After almost 15 years of Java programming I don't believe Java is a scripting language and know (at least to some extent) HOW it works. The question is not HOW, but WHY.

Answer (score 0):

There is no contradiction.

Object refers to a subclass of itself. That's not illegal, since in contrast to chicken, Strings don't have to be "developed" out of Objects, their class just need the Object class for construction, so both must be available at compile time.

If you want chicken-egg-confusion, have a look at Smalltalk: It uses Metaclass objects etc. and is a very good example of nearly everything of a language can be implemented in itself.